# Redis read from nearest replica, over all continents. (C# / .Net)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to host multiple redis over all continent, 1 Europe, 1 America, 1 Asia etc..
Master server will be in America.

Now, my problem is:
I have web apis distributed on those continents too. 1 Web API in Europe, 1 Web API in America etc...
If i want to write something in cache from Europe it will send to Master server from America (so it will take a lot but not problem), but if i want to read something i need to get nearest replica and read. Is there any implementation do to that automatically?
Should i configure each Web API to know where to get data?

```
Example: WebAPI-Europe in config: "GetCacheFrom": "ip_of_replica_from_europe"
Example: WebAPI-Africa in config: "GetCacheFrom": "ip_of_replica_from_africa",
```

but what about failover?

Answer (score 0):

There is no geo data available about servers, and the IP addresses are often private (VPN etc), so: again, no geo. Perhaps what might be sensible here is the library authors (myself and others) investing some time doing latency measurement are prioritisation based on that - sounds useful. But today: for vanilla SE.Redis your only option would be to supply just the most local replica address, but note that this won't work for "cluster" groups, since they advertise the other IP addresses and the library discovers them that way.

Comment: Wouldn't then this need him to do this at the cloud service provider level?

Comment: @DenisMicheal if we ignore "cluster" mode, then: not if you just give the lib the soap if the most local replica - assuming you're not behind a provider proxy, etc